# How to make proper alignment with printf

Tags: ruby, printing, printf

I am trying to make output that should look like this:

[image]

I am using this statement:

```
FILE_TYPES.each_key {|key| printf "%20s %s\n", "--[no]" + key.to_s, FILE_TYPES[key.to_sym]}
```

Its result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to stick to `printf`?

Comment: I don't have to. Do you know how to do this in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not insist on using `printf`,

```
puts "--[no]" + key.to_s.ljust(20) + FILE_TYPES[key.to_sym]
```

Comment: This one works perfect. I'm not sure I understood everything from doc about `ljust`, could you explain what it does?

Comment: Nikata, if you execute `'cat'.ljust(10)` in IRB, you'll understand. While you're at it, run`'cat'.rjust(10)`  and`'cat'.center(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use \t to give tab spaces for formatting strings. e.g.

```
printf "Name:\t Shahzad\nGender:\tMale\nAge:\t25\n"
```

and it would print result as

```
Name:    Shahzad
Gender: Male
Age:    25
=> nil
```

Comment: Sometimes (when a single item (column) is longer than tab skip), this may go wrong.

Comment: Yes, in most cases it works perfect, but not always.

Comment: If you expect large text variations, may use \t\t instead of single \t